# Undefined refernce for extClockType

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue with this program it keeps on giving me this error when i compile it

`C:\Users\dla\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAB92Md.o extClockType.cpp:(.text+0x74):` undefined reference to `clockType::printTime() const`

`C:\Users\dla\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAB92Md.o extClockType.cpp:(.text+0xeb):`undefined reference to `clockType::clockType(int, int, int)`

`C:\Users\dla\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAB92Md.o extClockType.cpp:(.text+0x156):` undefined reference to `clockType::clockType()`

I want to know what the issue is?

`clockType.h` header file

```
 //Header files section
  #ifndef H_clockType
  #define H_clockType
  #include<iostream>

  using namespace std;

//specification of the clockType class

  class clockType
  {
  public:
 //member functions
    void setTime(int, int, int);
    void getTime(int&, int&, int&) const;
    void printTime() const;
    void incrementSeconds();
    void incrementMinutes();
    void incrementHours();
    bool equalTime(const clockType&) const;

 //constructors
         clockType();
         clockType(int, int, int);

 private:
 //data fields
  int hr;
  int min;
  int sec;
 };
#endif
```

clockType.cpp file

```
// Header files section
 #include "clockType.h"
 using namespace std;

//implementation of the clockType class

//setTime function sets the hours, minutes, and seconds to the parameter values
 void clockType::setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
       if (0 <= hours && hours < 24)
          hr = hours;
       else
          hr = 0;

       if (0 <= minutes && minutes < 60)
          min = minutes;
       else
          min = 0;

       if (0 <= seconds && seconds < 60)
          sec = seconds;
       else
          sec = 0;
   }

//getTime function returns the hours, minutes, and seconds from the parameter values
   void clockType::getTime(int& hours, int& minutes,int& seconds) const
     {
        hours = hr;
        minutes = min;
        seconds = sec;
     }

//printTime function prints the time in 24-hours (00:00:00) format
   void clockType::printTime() const
     {
        if (hr < 10)
        cout << "0";
        cout << hr << ":";

        if (min < 10)
        cout << "0";
        cout << min << ":";

        if (sec < 10)
        cout << "0";
        cout << sec;
    }

//incrementHours function increments the time by 1 hour
 void clockType::incrementHours()
  {
     hr++;
     if (hr > 23)
     hr = 0;
  }

//incrementHours function increments the time by 1 minute
 void clockType::incrementMinutes()
  {
      min++;
      if (min > 59)
      {
        min = 0;
        incrementHours();
      }
  }

 //incrementHours function increments the time by 1 second
 void clockType::incrementSeconds()
  {
       sec++;
       if (sec > 59)
        {
          sec = 0;
          incrementMinutes();
        }
  }

 //equalTime function returns the equality of two times
 bool clockType::equalTime(const clockType & otherClock) const
   {
      return (hr == otherClock.hr &&
              min == otherClock.min &&
              sec== otherClock.sec);
   }

//default constructor sets the hours, minutes, and seconds to the default values
   clockType::clockType()
    {
       hr = 0;
       min = 0;
       sec = 0;
    }

//paramterized constructor sets the hours, minutes, and seconds to the parameter values
  clockType::clockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
   {
     setTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
   }
```

extClockType.h header file

```
#include "clockType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//extClockType extends clockType
  class extClockType : public clockType
   {
     public:
     // member functions
      void setTimeZone(string);
      string getTimeZone() const;
      void printTime() const;

    // constructors
      extClockType(int, int, int, string);
      extClockType();

    private:
   // data fields
      string tz;
   };
 #endif
```

extClockType.cpp file

```
//Header files section
   #include "extClockType.h"

//setTimeZone function sets the time zone to the parameter value
   void extClockType::setTimeZone(string timeZone)
     {
        tz = timeZone;
     }

//getTimeZone function returns the time zone
   string extClockType::getTimeZone() const
     {
       return tz;
     }

//printTime function prints the time zone
   void extClockType::printTime() const
     {
      // call the base class function
        clockType::printTime();
        cout << " " << tz << endl;
     }

  // parameerized constructor sets the clock time and time zone to the parameter values
      extClockType::extClockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds,string timeZone):clockType(hours, minutes, seconds)
       {
         tz = timeZone;
       }

//default constructor sets the clock time and time zone to the default values
 extClockType::extClockType() : clockType()
      {
         tz = "";
      }
```

Comment: The includes seem fine but also check your access modifiers.

Comment: These appear to be linker errors, not compiler errors. Make sure you have included clocktype.cpp in your project or makefile